# Supremum and functions property

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and $c>0$. Show that given any dissection $D$ of $[a,b]$.

Note: A dissection is also called a partition. $U(f,D)$ is the upper darboux sum. Geometrically, it is the area of the rectangles.

$U(f-c,D)\geq U(f,D)-c(b-a)$.

Proof Attempt:

Observe that $U(-c,D)=-c(b-a)$. So it suffices to show that $U(f-c,D)\geq U(f,D)+U(-c,D)$.

It suffices to show that $sup(f-c)=sup(f)-c$ where the supremum is defined on an interval A.

Observe that for each $x\in A$ $(f-c)(x)=f(x)-c$ $\leq$ $sup(f)-c$. Hence $sup(f-c) \leq sup(f)-c$.

Further observe that for each $x\in A$, $f(x)-c\leq sup(f-c)$ $\implies$ $f(x)\leq sup(f-c)+c$ hence $sup (f) - c \leq sup(f-c)$

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Hi.  For a question like this it is good to define what you mean by something like $ U(f, E) $.  This is not a universal notation, and it's not clear (at least to me) what you mean by it.  In fact, a "dissection" of an interval is also not a bit of terminology beknownst to me.  These terms can mean different things in different contexts.  For example, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dissection.html

Comment: Indeed, what is it you mean by a "dissection" of $[a,b]$. A partition, perhaps?

Comment: @Math1000 yup, I meant partition.

Comment: @Math1000 may you now look at my proof, please?